# How to build Angular6 project while having html,css and js files

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, architecture, microservices

I am developing a website using angular6 and spring boot with microservice architecture.

I have got the UI from designer team in the form of HTML, CSS, and JS file, whose structure is attached here [HTML and CSS files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDQyU.png)

Also, I had created a angular6 project named DIS, whose structure is attached here [Angular6 project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQjNf.png)

What will be the best way to start with angular 6?

How to include these files in angular6 project considering microservices architecture?

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question correctly.Yes you can do that.

**`Step 1:`** You need to create the Necessary components, Modules needed to build your website.

**`Step 2:`** Replace the components with the necessary HTML file and CSS file. As you generate a component with CLI you should have those 2 files just replace them.

When you have global CSS files that can be shared among other files as well. You can configure using Angular CLI.

Regards to microservices architecture, that does not have anything to do with your front end applicaiton, its totally on the server side. But you can consider while creating the components based on the services you have.

Comment: Definitely I can do this, but I have global CSS and JS files which are used in all html pages. Moreover, font style, calendar library and images are there then how to include all these files. And what about microservice architecture, will it be applied on angular part?

Comment: thank you for the solution, will try this one and post if it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

ng new ng6-proj --style=scss --routing

Just make changes in the main style.scss that will apply globally.
Images you can keep it anywhere, you just need to use it by providing its path